# Tree-based mathematical expressions using objects with assignable Func delegates

Tags: c#, linq, function, math, tree

I want to implement a generic tree data structure in C# that has a class `Tree<E>` which references a root `TreeNode<E>` object that contains a linked list of children and a single parent of the same node type. This is a basic tree structure and I don't really have any problems implementing this part.

I want to extend this tree structure to create `Function`, which extends `Tree<double>`, along with its compliment node type `Expression` which appropriately extends `TreeNode<double>`. I want to use this structure to represent mathematical functions which can be evaluated with the function's appropriate variables.

I'm currently in the design phase of this project so there are many ways I could implement this but I'm looking for the design that has the appropriate level of abstraction to cover all types of functions while still keeping their parameter signatures air-tight. For instance, I should be able to create a `Function` in run-time for the mathematical functions:

`f() = 42`, `f(x) = x^2`, `f(x, y) = x/y + 5`, etc.

If every `Expression` has its own list of children (sub-expressions which break down to define the process of the function given its arguments), then `Expression` should utilize some sort of evaluation method which takes in `double` values and spits out their scalar values (or if possible, extract this to the Vector level).

I'm not too experienced with functional languages like LINQ, but if anybody is, would there be a simple and powerful way to implement what I'm planning using that? It would be fantastic if I didn't have to create concrete classes for every sort of basic operation (like `SinExpression(X)` or `AdditionExpression(X,Y)` ones), but instead be able to define mathematical functions on the fly that could potentially be stored in a Dictionary, providing that all variables are going to either be other expressions, or boil down to floating-point values. At that point, concrete function classes could extend these abstracted ones if I needed to just by defining the evaluation function in the base constructor.

I also want to note that it's important to maintain the tree structure, because I plan to utilize these expressions in a separate program that will directly change a function's expression tree (changing nodes, removing branches, etc).

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do regular expression trees not suffice? i.e. `Expression<Func<double,double,double>> f = (x,y) => Math.Sin(x/y) + 5;` ? This can be *utilised* simply by calling `.Compile()` to get a `Func<double,double,double>`, or can be fully investigated as a tree if you want to look for points to swap for genetic algorithm purposes. Obviously you'll have to learn about the `Expression` API (or at least: the `ExpressionVisitor` API) to do swaps, rather than using the compiler to do that for you: but it isn't hard.

Comment: Totally called the genetic algorithm part. Alright thanks for the info, I'll check out those APIs. If you submit this as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already an API that represents complex operations as node trees; the LINQ `Expression` API. For a *trivial* example, you can get the compiler to build the trees for you  - for example:

```
Expression<Func<double,double,double>> f = (x,y) => Math.Sin(x/y) + 5;
```

This can be used to *evaluate* things by calling `Compile()`, i.e.

```
var func = f.Compile(); // this is a Func<double,double,double>
Console.WriteLine(func(12,5));
Console.WriteLine(func(23,4));
```

But the *expression tree* is more complex and can be arbitrarily inspected. Additionally you can use `ExpressionVisitor` to swap pieces out. For example, say we want to replace "x" with "ln(x)" as part of a random genetic mutation:

```
// swap x for ln(x)
var munged = SwapExpressionVisitor.Swap(
    f, // the lambda to rewrite
    f.Parameters[0], // "x"
    Expression.Call(typeof(Math), "Log", null, f.Parameters[0]) // ln(x)
); // (x, y) => (Sin((Log(x) / y)) + 5)

func = munged.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(func(12, 5));
Console.WriteLine(func(23, 4));
```

using a utility like:

```
class SwapExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public static Expression<T> Swap<T>(Expression<T> lambda,
        Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<T>(
            Swap(lambda.Body, from, to), lambda.Parameters);
    }
    public static Expression Swap(
        Expression body, Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        return new SwapExpressionVisitor(from, to).Visit(body);
    }
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public SwapExpressionVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a method similar to extending the ExpressionVisitor like you did for swapping parameter expressions that would allow me to dynamically add or remove branching operations in a function? For example if I had the function f = (x, y) => Math.Sin(x/y) + 5, is there a simple way to mutate that to (x, y) => Math.Sin(x/y) + (x - 5)? The idea would be to replace that subexpression (5) with another expression that allows 5 as one of its parameters (subtraction being like (p,q) => p-q). And the same question for removing the 5 altogether.

Comment: @WilliamThomas you can do *whatever you want to*; the `ExpressionVisitor` is just a convenient way of doing it all; but the `5` is just another expression node, in this case a `ConstantExpression`; you can replace that just as easily as another node, with anything you want to. Re removing the `5` altogether, if that is "removing the +5", then sure: find the `BinaryExpression` and replace it with either its own `.Left` or its own `.Right`: done.