# Generic Expression tree with 'OR' clause for each supplied property

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression-trees

I have created a generic search extension method for IQueryable that enables you to search for a single property to see if a search term is contained within it.

http://jnye.co/Posts/6/c%23-generic-search-extension-method-for-iqueryable

I now want to enable the user to select multiple properties to search within each, matching if ***any*** property contains the text.

**The code:**

The user enters the following code to perform this search:

```
string searchTerm = "Essex";
context.Clubs.Search(searchTerm, club => club.Name, club => club.County)

//Note: If possible I would rather something closer to the following syntax...
context.Clubs.Search(club => new[]{ club.Name, club.County}, searchTerm);
// ... or, even better, something similar to this...
context.Clubs.Search(club => new { club.Name, club.County}, searchTerm);
```

This will return any golf club with 'Essex' in the Name or as the County.

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> Search<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string searchTerm, params Expression<Func<TSource, string>>[] stringProperties)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            return source;
        }

        // The lamda I would like to reproduce:
        // source.Where(x => x.[property1].Contains(searchTerm)
        //                || x.[property2].Contains(searchTerm)
        //                || x.[property3].Contains(searchTerm)...)

        //Create expression to represent x.[property1].Contains(searchTerm)
        var searchTermExpression = Expression.Constant(searchTerm);


        //Build parameters
        var parameters = stringProperties.SelectMany(prop => prop.Parameters);
        Expression orExpression = null;

        //Build a contains expression for each property
        foreach (var stringProperty in stringProperties)
        {
            var checkContainsExpression = Expression.Call(stringProperty.Body, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), searchTermExpression);
            if (orExpression == null)
            {
                orExpression = checkContainsExpression;
            }

            //Build or expression for each property
            orExpression = Expression.OrElse(orExpression, checkContainsExpression);
        }

        var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
                                                   "Where",
                                                   new Type[] { source.ElementType },
                                                   source.Expression,
                                                   Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(orExpression, parameters));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(methodCallExpression);
    }
```

**The error**

[image: The error]

If I change the number of parameters supplied to 1:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(orExpression, parameters.First()));
```

I get a new error:

[image: The second error]

**UPDATE**

I have written [a post on the work discussed in this question](http://www.ninjanye.co.uk/2013/04/generic-iqueryable-or-search-on.html).  [Check it out on GitHub](https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions) too.

Comment: To do that you are going to have t re-write the tree, replacing the parameters from the "other" lambdas with the parameter from the one you want to use as the master. ExpressionVisitor is the tool to do that - a SwapExpressionVisitor is pretty easy to write (or use the one here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15293475/23354)

Comment: Would it be easier to change the method signature so that only one lambda is passed in? i.e. `.Search(club => new { club.Name, club.County}, searchTerm);` or to stick with the params implementation?

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem either way. It is actually pretty easy using ExpressionVisitor - sorry, I'm not at an IDE though

Comment: I would stick with the `params` way.  You are then given the array of `Expression` instances rather than one `Expression` which contains an array you'd then have to parse.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Ok, Thanks for the ExpressionVisitor pointer... I'll check it out

Comment: @jam40jeff: I'll stick with the params for now and concentrate on getting it working.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ninja if you can't figure it out, let me know - I'll have access to an IDE tomorrow :)

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell, I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go; you were pretty close - as I noted in comments, the key piece here is to use `ExpressionVisitor` to re-write the trees in terms of the single parameter you want to keep:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var data = new[] { new Foo { A = "x1", B = "y1", C = "y1" }, new Foo { A = "y2", B = "y2", C = "y2" },
            new Foo { A = "y3", B = "y3", C = "x3" } }.AsQueryable();

        var result = data.Search("x", x => x.A, x => x.B, x => x.C);

        foreach (var row in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", row.A, row.B, row.C);
        }
    }
    class Foo
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
    }
    public class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly Expression from, to;
        public SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
        {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }
        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
        }
        public static Expression Swap(Expression body, Expression from, Expression to)
        {
            return new SwapVisitor(from, to).Visit(body);
        }
    }
    public static IQueryable<TSource> Search<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string searchTerm, params Expression<Func<TSource, string>>[] stringProperties)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            return source;
        }
        if (stringProperties.Length == 0) return source.Where(x => false);


        // The lamda I would like to reproduce:
        // source.Where(x => x.[property1].Contains(searchTerm)
        //                || x.[property2].Contains(searchTerm)
        //                || x.[property3].Contains(searchTerm)...)

        //Create expression to represent x.[property1].Contains(searchTerm)
        var searchTermExpression = Expression.Constant(searchTerm);


        var param = stringProperties[0].Parameters.Single();
        Expression orExpression = null;

        //Build a contains expression for each property
        foreach (var stringProperty in stringProperties)
        {
            // re-write the property using the param we want to keep
            var body = SwapVisitor.Swap(stringProperty.Body, stringProperty.Parameters.Single(), param);

            var checkContainsExpression = Expression.Call(
                body, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), searchTermExpression);

            if (orExpression == null)
            {
                orExpression = checkContainsExpression;
            }
            else
            {   // compose
                orExpression = Expression.OrElse(orExpression, checkContainsExpression);
            }
        }

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(orExpression, param);
        return source.Where(lambda);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, did manage to work it out last night once you pointed me to ExptessionVisitor. Thanks for taking the time to point me in the right direction, and again this morning with a full answer.

Comment: @NinjaNye no problem; I didn't see any updates so I assumed it was still pending :)

Comment: Was too late by the time I cracked it plus didn't want to steel your rep so thought I'd let you have the honour

Comment: @NinjaNye note the last two lines here are *very* different to what you had - you might want to simplify that if you're still using the complex version

Comment: Good shout, I had missed that