# Search on all fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an Entity, `Device`, I'd like a user to be able to search on all fields (ideally all, i'd cope with just text).  How can I do this without having to explicitly do

```
devices.Where(d => 
    d.prop1.Contains(searchterm) || 
    d.prop2.Contains(searchterm))
```

This must happen on the database though, not in the returned objects.

**Edit**

I had already tried one of the comments, the following, which didnt work

```
var stringProperties = typeof(Device)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == deviceSettingValue.GetType());
var matches = devices
    .Where(device => stringProperties.Any(prop => prop.GetValue(device, null) == deviceSettingValue));
var fullmatches = matches.ToList();
```

The error is

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

Comment: In your first code snippet, don't you mean to do `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: Yes, it was pseudo code so made a mistake - ill update

Comment: This might help then... http://stackoverflow.com/a/15564970/1663001

Comment: You can't use reflection in the query because EF doesn't know how to translate it to SQL. You need to build lambda-expression which accesses to properties (i.e. `d.Prop1.Contains(searchTerm) || d.Prop2.Contains(searchTerm)`. This article might be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can dynamically build an expression based on the properties of the entity like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> CreateSearchQuery<T>(DbSet<T> db_set , string value) where T:class
{
    IQueryable<T> query = db_set;

    List<Expression> expressions = new List<Expression>();

    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "p");

    MethodInfo contains_method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof (string)))
    {
        MemberExpression member_expression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, prop.Name);

        ConstantExpression value_expression = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));

        MethodCallExpression contains_expression = Expression.Call(member_expression, contains_method, value_expression);

        expressions.Add(contains_expression);
    }

    if (expressions.Count == 0)
        return query;

    Expression or_expression = expressions[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < expressions.Count; i++)
    {
        or_expression = Expression.OrElse(or_expression, expressions[i]);
    }

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        or_expression, parameter);

    return query.Where(expression);
}
```

This method takes in a `DbSet` and the value you want to search for. It loops through the properties that are of type `string` and for each property it creates a "contains" expression (e.g. `p => p.Name.Contains("test")`).

Then it aggregates the expressions with an OR expression.

You can use this method like this:

```
var query = CreateSearchQuery(context.Devices, "name");

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PropertyType and GetType()

```
devices.Where(prop =>
prop.PropertyType == query.GetType())
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all properties of the Device class.

```
var properties = typeof(Device).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == query.GetType());
```

then find all Devices that have at least one property with value equal to the query.

```
context.Device.Where(device => properties.Any(prop => prop.GetValue(device, null) == query));
```

Comment: I had already tried this but it didnt work because of `Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`